# Adding an algorithm in Latex changes the layout of my figures

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmic

I want to add an algorithm in my latex file. I add it by implementing the following:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
.....

\begin{algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \caption{Waypoint-reduction algorithm.}
            \procedure REDUCE \\
            \state $i \gets N_*$
            \state $\mathbb{P} \gets$ InitializePath
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
```

However, when I do so, it also changes the layout of my figures and their captions. This is before the algortihm package is added:

[image]

And here is after:

[image]

Does anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: Welcome :) // Can you please EDIT and complete your code? It's not clear, which document type you use, where and how you include images etc. Your code snippet can't compile without guessing about these things. We like to see code, which compiles AND shows your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Of course! The latex document is approx. 20-30 pages. Don't know how it's best show share it, since it happens to the whole document.. Maybe just share the file for setting up the document?

Comment: Best way is to create a copy and delete all unnecessary or duplicate parts. The final code won‘t have more than about 30-50 lines, roughly. If you can compile it and still see your problem, then it‘s time to replace your current code snippet.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks:) just needed to add the packages after the rest

Comment: Specifically, algorithm should be loaded after float (if it has options).  Otherwise float get loaded without options.